# Excessive Data Consumption

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7

I need some help, would be thankful if someone give me the idea for this.

We've a wireless internet connection in our office and the day since then our office has switched from a dynamic IP to a static IP, the data consumption has increased more than doubled.

1. We have a 20 GB monthly limit but do not have any internet consumption at our office except the emails we receive and the anti-virus or software updates (which are manual). The only thing we do is to connect the software on the machine via remote desktop (as we have 2 office locations), which i don't think, could be a cause of excessive usage.
2. We have even put a restriction recently so that only the IPs (which we have added in our modem firmware) could connect to the internet, but event then within a week we have got a notice from the provider that we have exceeded our 50% data consumption limit.
3. Someone has told me that the modem has been configured to use extranet (don't know how to check that) which should be reset to use intranet to avoid this extra usage. By this way, we won't be able to use the static IP, but our usage would decrease gradually (not sure about this, would that help?). 
   We are using windows 7 on all PCs
   Any ideas?

Comment: Perform a packet capture to examine who/what is consuming your bandwidth.

Comment: Could you please guide how to do that? As I don't have much info about networks

Comment: @abb Are you the administrator for this network? Your question was closed because you do not seem to have the experience or the access necessary to actually investigate/resolve this issue. [As such the best advice we can give you is "Get a professional consultant in to help"](http://serverfault.com/a/534121/32986) - explaining how to use Wireshark or other packet capture tools and interpret the results is a bit much for a Q&A exchange.

Answer (score 1):

If this was my site I'd take a couple of steps but please understand none of these is trivial.

1. Set up a proxy box to cache and log network traffic (squid is a good, free option)
2. Set up a WSUS server to patch the machines, MS patching can generate a LOT of traffic
3. Read the logs on the proxy box to figure out who your high talkers are

Right now you do not have the tools or information to address this problem. It sounds like you may want to get a consultant in or spend a few days reading & testing things in a lab.